# Numpy: Average of values corresponding to unique coordinate positions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

So, I have been browsing stackoverflow for quite some time now, but I can't seem to find the solution for my problem

Consider this

```
import numpy as np
coo = np.array([[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [3, 4], [1, 2], [5, 6], [1, 2]])
values = np.array([1, 2, 4, 2, 1, 6, 1])
```

The coo array contains the (x, y) coordinate positions
x = (1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 5, 1)
y = (2, 3, 4, 4, 2, 6, 2)

and the values array some sort of data for this grid point.

Now I want to get the average of all values for each unique grid point.
For example the coordinate (1, 2) occurs at the positions (0, 4, 6), so for this point I want `values[[0, 4, 6]]`.

How could I get this for all unique grid points?

Comment: What is the dtype of `coo`? Are the values always non-negative ints? Is there a maximum value for the coordinates?

Comment: the dtype in my case would be "float" and the coordinates can take arbitrary values, also negative ones 

Comment: @HansSnah I hope you are not trying equality checks on floats in a real app. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can sort `coo` with [`np.lexsort`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.lexsort.html) to bring the duplicate ones in succession. Then run [`np.diff`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html) along the rows to get a mask of starts of unique XY's in the sorted version. Using that mask, you can create an ID array that would have the same ID for the duplicates. The ID array can then be used with [`np.bincount`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html) to get the summation of all values with the same ID and also their counts and thus the average values, as the final output. Here's an implementation to go along those lines -

```
# Use lexsort to bring duplicate coo XY's in succession
sortidx = np.lexsort(coo.T)
sorted_coo =  coo[sortidx]

# Get mask of start of each unique coo XY
unqID_mask = np.append(True,np.any(np.diff(sorted_coo,axis=0),axis=1))

# Tag/ID each coo XY based on their uniqueness among others
ID = unqID_mask.cumsum()-1

# Get unique coo XY's
unq_coo = sorted_coo[unqID_mask]

# Finally use bincount to get the summation of all coo within same IDs 
# and their counts and thus the average values
average_values = np.bincount(ID,values[sortidx])/np.bincount(ID)
```

Sample run -

```
In [65]: coo
Out[65]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [2, 3],
       [3, 4],
       [3, 4],
       [1, 2],
       [5, 6],
       [1, 2]])

In [66]: values
Out[66]: array([1, 2, 4, 2, 1, 6, 1])

In [67]: unq_coo
Out[67]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [2, 3],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 6]])

In [68]: average_values
Out[68]: array([ 1.,  2.,  3.,  6.])
```

Comment: Very clever! thanks. I already have it implemented in my code! 

Comment: You can get the counts from the positions of the indices of the result of `diff`, that's basically what `np.unique` does when you ask for `return_counts=True`, and it is typically faster than calling `bincount`.

Comment: @Jaime Ah yeah that could be used for counting too. Didn't know about the performance numbers related to these two approaches, good to know, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `where`:

```
>>> values[np.where((coo == [1, 2]).all(1))].mean()
1.0
```

Comment: I guess that would work if I loop over all unique values, but I would like to avoid that 

Answer (score 1):

It is very likely going to be faster to flatten your indices, i.e.:

```
flat_index = coo[:, 0] * np.max(coo[:, 1]) + coo[:, 1]
```

then use `np.unique` on it:

```
unq, unq_idx, unq_inv, unq_cnt = np.unique(flat_index,
                                           return_index=True,
                                           return_inverse=True,
                                           return_counts=True)
unique_coo = coo[unq_idx]
unique_mean = np.bincount(unq_inv, values) / unq_cnt
```

than the similar approach using `lexsort`.

But under the hood the method is virtually the same.

Comment: Also very neat, however I discovered that, when applied to my data, the flat index in not unique and the results are somewhat difference for certain combinations compared to the lexsort approach

Comment: That's probably because I messed up: you need to multiply row indices by the largest column index, not by the largest row index. I have edited above, should work fine now.

Comment: The OP clarified [in the comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31878240/numpy-average-of-values-corresponding-to-unique-coordinate-positions/31880196#comment51674739_31878240) that the `coo` values can be floats. If `coo = np.array([[0, 2], [0.5, 1]])`, then `flat_index` would equal `array([ 2.,  2.])`, thus combining two coordinates which are not the same.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple one-liner using the [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) package (disclaimer: I am its author):

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
unique, mean = npi.group_by(coo).mean(values)
```

Should be comparable to the currently accepted answer in performance, as it does similar things under the hood; but all in a well tested package with a nice interface.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the comment, but have not tested/implemented your routine since I do not want to keep the number of dependencies in all my projects as low as possible. 

Comment: It is both pip and conda installable on all platforms; but thats your call. Feel free to copy paste the relevant bits out of my repo as well.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is using JAX `unique` and `grad`. This approach might be particularly fast because it allows you to run on an accelerator (CPU, GPU, or TPU).

```
import functools
import jax
import jax.numpy as jnp


@jax.grad
def _unique_sum(unique_values: jnp.ndarray, unique_inverses: jnp.ndarray, values: jnp.ndarray):
    errors = unique_values[unique_inverses] - values
    return -0.5*jnp.dot(errors, errors)


@functools.partial(jax.jit, static_argnames=['size'])
def unique_mean(indices, values, size):
    unique_indices, unique_inverses, unique_counts = jnp.unique(indices, axis=0, return_inverse=True, return_counts=True, size=size)
    unique_values = jnp.zeros(unique_indices.shape[0], dtype=float)
    return unique_indices, _unique_sum(unique_values, unique_inverses, values) / unique_counts


coo = jnp.array([[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [3, 4], [1, 2], [5, 6], [1, 2]])
values = jnp.array([1, 2, 4, 2, 1, 6, 1])
unique_coo, unique_mean = unique_mean(coo, values, size=4)
print(unique_mean.block_until_ready())
```

The only weird thing is the `size` argument since JAX requires all array sizes to be fixed / known beforehand. If you make `size` too small it will throw out good results, too large it will return nan's.